# Is an injective smooth map an immersion?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds. An immersion is a smooth map $f: M \rightarrow N$ whose pushforward is injective at each point.

Is a smooth injective map an immersion?

We can actually simplify the question further.

Suppose $f : M \rightarrow N$ is a smooth injective map. Suppose $(U, \phi)$ and $(V, \psi)$ are smooth charts for $M$ and $N$ respectively. Fix $p \in U$. Then

$$ f_\ast = ( \psi^{-1}\circ \psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1} \circ \phi)_{\ast} = (\psi^{-1})_\ast \circ (\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1})_\ast \circ \phi_\ast $$

As $\phi$ and $\psi$ are diffeomorphisms, $\phi_\ast$ and $(\psi^{-1})_\ast$ are linear isomorphisms.

Therefore, if $(\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1})_\ast$ is injective then $f_\ast$ is injective.

This shows that if every smooth injective map between open subsets of euclidean space is an immersion, then every smooth injective map between smooth manifolds is an immersion.

Comment: What about $f(x)=x^3$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$..?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no.

Here's an example, which is based on an example I gave in my multivariable calculus discussion section recently.

Let $M$ be $(0,\pi)$ with coordinate $t$. Let $N$ be $\mathbb R^2$ with coordinates $x$ and $y$. Define a map $x(t)=\sin(t)$, $y(t)=\sin(t)$ for $t$ in $(0,\pi/2]$ and $x(t)=2-\cos(t-\pi/2)$, $y(t)=2-\cos(t-\pi/2)$ for $t$ in $(\pi/2,\pi)$. This map is smooth and injective on points but the derivative is zero at $t=\pi/2$.

Edit: Ok, I got a bit too excited about using multivariable calculus. As algori mentions, $t^3$ is a simpler example. Or just taking one of the coordinate functions in my original example works too. There's no need for multivariable calculus.

Comment: I give a homework problem to my manifolds students ,asking them to construct a smooth injection (an immersion at all but one point)from $\mathbb R$ and onto the "corner space" $(x,y)$ such that $x \geq 0$ and $y=0$ union $x=0$ and $y \geq 0$.

Comment: Kevin -- this is not continuous;) On a more serious level: $t\mapsto t^3$ would do, no multivariate calculus necessary.

Comment: algori: I fixed it. And yeah that works too. 

Comment: thanks for the help! The cubic example was just what i was looking for. i feel a bit silly now though 

Comment: It's interesting if you think about this in terms of Toen's "Geometric Contexts". I see it as a failure of the classical theory that injective morphisms do not correspond to immersions. Rather, if we replace the classical notions with functors of points, a lot of these "degeneracies", if they could be called that, disappear to some extent. This is because injective morphisms (our choice of morphisms depends on the geometric context, of course) do in fact become "open" immersions.

Comment: Open immersions generally aren't injective, either.  This isn't a "failure" of the theory you're seeing.   Your expectations are too narrow. 

Comment: Check out cours 2 page 4 example 4.  In fact, the open immersions are characterized precisely by being injective.  Like any good functor of points theory, the underlying topological space is not important.  Precisely, open immersions are injective (at the sheaf level) local diffeomorphisms.

Comment: When I said "morphisms," I probably should have said "structure morphisms", which are denoted by P. They are a distinguished class of morphisms that determine which sheaves are geometric varieties (generalization of schemes, manifolds in that they are "covered by" open immersions of representable functors). 

Comment: They're local diffeos, sure.  But a covering map is a local diffeo without a right or left inverse, in general. 

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  The reason that the functors of points are especially nice is that we can characterize our maps as actual injective local diffeomorphisms without really referring to the underlying spaces by specifying everything locally.  That's what I really like about sheaves in general.  

Answer (score 5):

For a smooth injective map $f:M\rightarrow N$, there is only an obstruction to be $f$ an immersion, and it is that its rank is not constant.

Comment: To reformulate @argtororella, a smooth injective map of **constant rank** is an immersion. You can also see [wikipedia, constant rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(differential_topology)) for further details.